# Merging Transparent PNGs results in inconsistent black dots

Tags: php, png, gd, gd2

I'm merging some transparent PNGs in PHP with GD. I have a bunch of numbers done up on a transparent background that I put together onto a final image. Running the script on one server with the following GD config:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.2.1
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.10
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled
```

It works perfectly. My result looks something like:

http://upload.nucleardog.com/rc97

When I run the same script on another server, gd configured as such:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.0
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.2
T1Lib Support => enabled
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.44
WBMP Support => enabled
```

I end up with something that looks more like:

http://upload.nucleardog.com/19c3

Does anyone have any idea why the transparency is failing to copy in such an inconsistent manner? Different copies of the same number (identical source image - not reloaded in between) copied into different places in the result image have a different pattern in the black pixels.

A copy of the script I'm using is available [here](http://upload.nucleardog.com/ox5b) for anyone that would like to dig through. It loads the numbers around line `69`. It copies the numbers on to an intermediate image at `155-165`. That intermediate step is copied onto the result image at `197-231`.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix the script on this specific server? Is it an issue with it not using the bundled GD?

Thanks for any ideas!

**Edit:** The machine with issues is running PHP 5.3.3:

```
adam:~$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 16:07:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
adam:~/$
```

The one without is running the same:

```
adam@server1 [~]$ php-cli -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2010 16:36:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
adam@server1 [~]$
```

The one with the problems is a Ubuntu box. Both php and gd were installed from apt (php5 and php5-gd).

Comment: So the dates are a bit fuzzy, but it looks like GD *2.0* was released some time in 2002.  PHP has bundled a version of GD since **4.3.0**, released in late 2002.  The only way you'd ever see a non-bundled version of GD is if PHP was compiled against it on that machine... *and then you'd be dealing with a machine with libraries that haven't been patched in nine years.*  Either `phpinfo` is wrong or the machine is horked.  Or both.  What's the PHP version in use on the horked machine?

Comment: The Debian `php5-gd` package relies on the *external* GD library.  It's very likely that the Ubuntu one follows that pattern.  So, it's clearly not going to be actually using 2.0 directly, but a more modern version.  However, that still doesn't explain the behavior...